# Creating an MSPaint clone in Python?

Tags: python, save, clone, paint

I'm looking to create a VERY simple MSPaint clone in Python with the ability to save and load files.  Ideally the program would limit the user to a 4-color palette.  What would be the simplest way of going about this?  Keep in mind that I'm fairly new to programming, so any assistance could be helpful.

Comment: 1) Learn python 2) Pick a GUI toolkit (PyQT, PyGTK, Tkinter, WxPython) 3) Go through a number of tutorials for your chosen toolkit 4) If your question is not already answered, repeat (3).

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Not homework, haha.
Guess I'll check out PyQT.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to take a look at [pygame](http://www.pygame.org).

The answers to this question should be helpful: [How to create MS Paint clone with Python and pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/597369/311220)