# Freehand drawing in Pygame

Tags: pygame

I'm trying to make some experiment using Pygame. I'm trying to write a simple piece of code to be able to draw on the screen using the mouse.
This is the code I wrote:

```
import pygame
import pygame.time
import graphics

def init_surface():
    DISPLAY_SURFACE = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480), pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
    return graphics.ViewportSurface(DISPLAY_SURFACE)

def init_mouse_pointer():
    mouse_pointer_color = pygame.Color(255, 64, 64)
    mouse_pointer = graphics.MousePointer(5, mouse_pointer_color, graphics.Point(0,0))
    return mouse_pointer, mouse_pointer_color

def main():
    pygame.init()

    window_surface = init_surface()

    center_point = graphics.Point(0,0)

    mouse_pointer, mouse_pointer_color = init_mouse_pointer()

    color = pygame.Color(255, 255, 255)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while True:
        # Event handling
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.NOEVENT:
                continue
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

        # Update mouse status  
        mouse_position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()     
        mouse_position_viewport = window_surface.convert_coordinate_from_display_to_viewport(graphics.Point(mouse_position[0], mouse_position[1]))
        mouse_pointer.set_position(mouse_position_viewport)

        # Update screen
        window_surface.draw_point(center_point, color)
        mouse_pointer.draw(window_surface)
        window_surface.flip()
        clock.tick(180)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problem is the that moving the mouse I don't get a continuous line but a dotted line, as you can see in the following picture:

[image]
For which reason the line is not continuous? Is there something wrong in my code? I don't understand where the problem is. What's your idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create MS Paint clone with Python and pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597369/how-to-create-ms-paint-clone-with-python-and-pygame)

Comment: @skrx Sorry, I don't think this is a duplicated. In [How to create MS Paint clone with Python and pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50067292/freehand-drawing-in-pygame) they talk about how to shape the brush to avoid the gaps in the draw, they don't address the main problem I'm trying to find now.
What I would like to understand is what is the root cause of this behaviour.

Comment: The answers show you how to draw continuously between the points that you get when you move the mouse. Is that not what you want to do?

Comment: I agree that this can be a solution but I would like to understand better what is causing the issue. Is the python code too slow to be able to draw all the points? Or there is something more?

Comment: That's just the normal behavior. If the mouse moves too fast, then it will be for example at (200, 150) in one frame and at (300, 200) in the next frame, so you won't get a line. Pygame doesn't generate the points between the frames for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like skrx said, the mouse is simply moving too fast. This happens lots of times, and I have had this problem occur to me as well. The solution it to connect the points with a line. Look at this:

```
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
dots = []

while True:
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    dots.append(mouse_pos)
    pygame.draw.lines(surface, (255, 255, 255), False, dots)  # use this, much more efficient then drawing every line between the points
    # keep closed as False
```

What this does is it appends a new set of points every loop and with `pygame.draw.lines` it connects all of them.  Hope this helps.