# Pygame erasing colour to make it transparent

Tags: python, pygame

I want to have a background surface with an image and people can draw on another surface that is transparent then when I erase the drawing on the transparent surface, the pixel will be back to transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for the drawing part you could base your code off the code in a post like this one:
[How to create MS Paint clone with Python and pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597369/how-to-create-ms-paint-clone-with-python-and-pygame)

For the background, you could use

```
Im = pygame.image.load("image.png")
screen.blit(Im, (0,0))
```

to paste an image behind the drawing part.

To erase, set the brush color to (0, 0, 0, 0)